# Trigonometry angles question

Tags: trigonometry

The top of a cedar tree broken by the wind hits the ground 12 yards from the base of the tree. If the top of the tree makes an angle of 19 degrees with the ground, what was the original height of the tree?

Comment: Where you stuck$?$ Show your work

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :- draw the diagram with the given information in the question .

$x\cos \left(19\right)=12$     ( where $x$ is length of broken part of tree ) .

Then, $x=12.69$(approx.)
Now apply **Pythagoras theorem** to get length of other remaining part of tree ( its coming around 4.13) add both you will get the height of the tree.